# How does one train the input-to-hidden weights in a neural network?

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am busy making a basic neural network in java with three inputs, one hidden layer with two hidden neurons and one output neuron.I have previously made a smaller one with three inputs and one output but no hidden layers, where I used some basic calculus for the back propagation and the cost was calculated using the formula (prediction-target)^2. Both of these NNs do not use an activation function like sigmoid as they predict a value, not a binary output.

My problem comes in when I try to train my bigger NN with a hidden layer. The basic calculus method I used for my first one does not work.

Could anyone help me by telling me how to train the NN with the hidden layer? (the Mathematical formula)

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVId8KMsdUU) on YouTube should be a good resource to start with! If you're just interested in the mathematical formula, you can skip to the end of the second part. I recommend watching both videos if you want to know how the weights are updated. Using this video, I developed following algorithm:

```
public void applyBackpropagation(double expectedOutput[]){

    for (int i = 0; i < expectedOutput.length; i++) {
        double d = expectedOutput[i];
        if (d < 0 || d > 1) {
            if (d < 0)
                expectedOutput[i] = 0 + epsilon;
            else
                expectedOutput[i] = 1 - epsilon;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for(Neuron n : outputLayer){
        ArrayList<Connection> connections = n.getAllInConnections();
        double Ok = n.getOutput();
        double tk = expectedOutput[i];
        double dk = Ok*(1-Ok)*(Ok - tk);
        for(Connection c : connections){
            double dw = -learningRate * dk * c.leftNeuron.getOutput();
            c.setWeight(c.getWeight() + dw);
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(Neuron n : hiddenLayer){
        ArrayList<Connection> connections = n.getAllInConnections();
        double Oj = n.getOutput();
        double sum = 0;
        i = 0;
        for(Neuron out_n : outputLayer){
            double out_ok = out_n.getOutput();
            double out_tk = expectedOutput[i];
            double out_dk = out_ok*(1-out_ok)*(out_ok - out_tk);
            double wjk = getWeightByNeurons(n, out_n);
            sum += out_dk * wjk;
            i++;
        }
        double dj = Oj*(1-Oj)*sum;

        for(Connection c : connections){
            double dw = -learningRate * dj * c.getFromNeuron().getOutput();
            c.setWeight(c.getWeight() + dw);
        }
    }
}
```

The activation function used was sigmoid.